# Nailed my /boot, which was on USB. How can I recreate it?

Tags: boot, usb, data-recovery

I had my /boot on a USB, which was configured as a physical volume with two logical volumes.  My root disk is fine, but I need to recreate the USB with grub and /boot, including kernel(s) and initramfs.  Anyone have a suggesting of what path I might follow?

Answer (score -1):

Boot into a live system. Open you system partition in Nautilus and copy the path (`ctrl + L` shows you the path). Then: `sudo gedit [path you copied]/etc/fstab`. In the file that opens, remove the line with `/boot` in the middle, save and close. Then unmount the partition in Nautilus.

Execute:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Assuming your system partition is `/dev/sda`. You can easily find this out by entering `sudo fdisk -l`. It will give you some output with one for every physical drive (like your HDD or your USB stick) and something like `Disk /dev/sda:` in the beginning of every block.

Comment: That's missing initramfs though. Edit your answer to include that

Comment: Ya, I neither have a kernel nor initramfs.  All that'll do is give me grub at the start of the disk, and the /boot/grub directory.  I do know how to pivot into a system from a live-CD. Is there some way I can use the /boot on the live CD?

Comment: You can't simply copy the folder.